# R: Calculating missing monthly values

Tags: r

I got a data set with monthly values, except for the end of each quarter, where there is quarterly aggregated data. I'm interested in the monthly values for these months as well, but this needs to be calculated. So for the 3rd, 6th, 9th and 12th month, there needs to be a calculation that subtracts the previous two months' values.

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c('AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA',
                          'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB'),
                 Month = c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6',
                           '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'),
                 Year = c(2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
                          2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017),
                 Value = c(100, 105, 315, 115, 120, 360,
                           100, 110, 330, 130, 140, 420))
```

In this toy example, the value for AAA in month 3 of 2017 is 110, and this value should replace 315. I'm trying to create a code that will do this for all names, all years, all quarters, but I can't seem to find a way to automate it.

Comment: You can try `require(dplyr) ; df %>% group_by(Name) %>% mutate(value2 = ifelse(Month%in%c(3,6,9,12),Value-(lag(Value,1)+lag(Value,2)),Value))`

Comment: Is your data.frame always complete (i.e. all months before the quarter will be present) ?

Comment: You might also want to add `Year` to your `group_by`, assuming the dataset has more than one year in it.

Comment: @digEmAll Yes, that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(Value = ifelse(as.numeric(Month) %% 3 == 0, 
                             Value - lag(Value,1) - lag(Value, 2), 
                             Value))
```

Comment: This gives the error message "attempt to use zero-length variable name"

Comment: Apologies, there was some error in the code, it should be working now

Answer (score 1):

Using [`ave`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.3/topics/ave) :

```
df$Value <- ave(1:nrow(df),df$Name,df$Year,
                FUN = function(x){
                  w <- which(df$Month[x] %in% c('3','6','9','12'))
                  v <- df$Value[x]
                  v[w] <- v[w] - v[w-1] - v[w-2]
                  v
                })

> df
   Name Month Year Value
1   AAA     1 2017   100
2   AAA     2 2017   105
3   AAA     3 2017   110
4   AAA     4 2017   115
5   AAA     5 2017   120
6   AAA     6 2017   125
7   BBB     1 2017   100
8   BBB     2 2017   110
9   BBB     3 2017   120
10  BBB     4 2017   130
11  BBB     5 2017   140
12  BBB     6 2017   150
```

Note : `df` needs to be sorted at the very least by `Month` ascending

Answer (score 1):

A possibility with `data.table` if it is sorted by `Name`, `Year`, `Month` as in the example:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, Month := as.numeric(Month)]
df[Month %% 3 == 0,
   Value := Value - df[Month %% 3 != 0,Value][c(T,F)] - df[Month %% 3 != 0,Value][c(F,T)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach, creating quarter dummies and grouping.

The last line evaluates which Months are divisible by 3 and calculates your intended value.

To use it for whole Year just change the `replicate` command to `rep(1:4, each = 3)`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Name, Year) %>%
  mutate(quarter = rep(1:2, each = 3)) %>%
  group_by(Name, Year, quarter) %>%
  mutate(Value = ifelse(Month %% 3 == 0, 2*Value - sum(Value), Value))

# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   Name, Year, quarter [4]
   Name  Month  Year Value quarter
   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <int>
 1 AAA      1. 2017.  100.       1
 2 AAA      2. 2017.  105.       1
 3 AAA      3. 2017.  110.       1
 4 AAA      4. 2017.  115.       2
 5 AAA      5. 2017.  120.       2
 6 AAA      6. 2017.  125.       2
 7 BBB      1. 2017.  100.       1
 8 BBB      2. 2017.  110.       1
 9 BBB      3. 2017.  120.       1
10 BBB      4. 2017.  130.       2
11 BBB      5. 2017.  140.       2
12 BBB      6. 2017.  150.       2
```